# Upgrade SPF'x to 1.6.0

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, adal

In a solution i had 2 SPF'x web parts and 3 SPF'x Extensions. I need to upgrade the web part to SPF'x 1.6.0. So i have updated my package.json references to 1.6.0. Then i had ran the "npm install" command. Once i done both these, it throws the below error.

"...\node_modules\@microsoft\sp-build-web\node_modules\@m icrosoft\node-core-library\lib\JsonSchema.js:178 throw new Error(prefix + os.EOL + ^

Error: JSON validation failed: D:\Bloom\Code\BloomWebparts\config\tslint.json

Error: #/ (Defines configuration options for the...) Additional properties not allowed: lintConfig,useDefaultConfigAsBase,remo veExistingRules,displayAsWarning at validateObjectWithCallback".

Am i missing anything? What is the proper way to upgrade the solution to SPF'x 1.6.0?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this post should answer your question [Updating SPFX breaks gulp](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248853/updating-spfx-breaks-gulp/248901#248901)
Short story: 1.6 projects don't have a tslint.json in the config folder anymore, remove it.