# Gulp serve error - No valid rules for TypeScript files

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-experience, modern-pages

I received the error message
 below when I tried to run `gulp serve` on a tile web part that I got from a starter kit from https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-starter-kit/issues/131

[image]

Node version:
[image]

UPDATE:

I followed the solution on this question: [Updating SPFX breaks gulp](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248853/updating-spfx-breaks-gulp) It got rid of the error message above. I then followed the direction of the first question below by *Jerry_MSFT* and:

- made sure `npm outdated -g` wasn't throwing any mismatches
- I updated my `Node.js` and `SPFX`

Then I found I had more errors, so I installed `gulp 3.9.1`, I installed the latest `node-gyp`, and made sure my npm in my 'Program files' was up-to-date

Now I only have one error, **Error - [tslint] No valid rules have been specified for TypeScript files**. Here is the error on the workbench:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you ran `npm install` command after downloading the code from github?

Comment: yes I have, but I have made changed the versions of node and gulp. I will redo the `npm install`

Comment: I rebuilt the npm install, and used gulp 3.9.1. I get a different error message: "Error: Cannot find module './ModelReferenceResolver'". Do I need gulp 4.0.2 with CLI 2.2.0? Is there an imbalance with Local gulp 3.9.1 and CLI gulp 2.2.0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This article gave me a successful `gulp serve` and no more error!
[Replace your tslint and tsconfig files with the ones on this page](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/spfx-upgrading-to-latest-version-1-9-1-issues-and-solutions/)

Answer (score 2):

Please use npm install for ..\sp-starter-kit-master\solution folder path:

[image]

Then use gulp serve in the same path like this:

[image]

In workbench, The Tiles web part can be found and use:
[image]

Comment: I went back and used the starter kit master instead of my isolated tiles. I suppose something was out of date? I did what you said and got an error 'Error - [spfx-serve] Error: Invalid glob argument: 
Error - 'spfx-serve' sub task errored after 1.77 s 
 Invalid glob argument: 
 'serve' errored after 1.81 s' - node -v
v8.15.1
npm -v
6.13.4
gulp -v
CLI version: 2.2.0
Local version: 4.0.2

Comment: I‘m using Node.js v10.17.0 and SPFX 1.9.1, no problem when build with gulp serve.
You can use "npm install @microsoft/generator-sharepoint@latest -g" to update the SPFX solution generator and suggested use Node.js v10 to test and deploy. For detailed information, please read this official document:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/toolchain/update-latest-packages

Comment: I updated my node to 10 and spfx to 1.9.1 but got the same error. I followed the official Microsoft docs and found there is a mismatch with my nodes, the current npm is 6.11.3 and the 'npm -v' is the correct 6.13.4. This has to cause an issue...

Comment: This is the location of the current npm: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm. I replaced it with https://github.com/npm/cli and now there is no imbalance when I run npm outdated -g. That didn't solve the problem I get the same error.

Comment: `npm audit fix --force` was throwing an error as well, my node-gyp was old `ERR! node-gyp -v v5.0.5` so I replaced it here https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp. ...Once again it did not solve the error message from this question which is a problem on all of my web parts not just the starter kit package. No matter what web part I try to run I get the same error.

Comment: sp-module-interfaces was outdated as well, updated it here `npm i @microsoft/sp-module-interfaces`

Comment: Try to uninstall Node.js firstly and then configure dev environment based on this document:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment
Delete all the starterkit folder, redownload from GitHub, unzip and build with the step above.
In my side, there is no such issue will working fine...

Comment: You are absolutely right the master tiles works fine, but I want just the tiles. I don't need or want the extra web parts. I went back to my Isolated tiles and found a new error and posted it